# MYSQL: SUB QUERY WITH LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys I would like to know how can I achieve on output the total members

here is the query

```
SELECT 
     field1,
     field2,
     (select count(*) 
       from table2 as t2 
       where t2.field5 LIKE '%' + t1.field2 + '%') as total_row 
FROM table1 as t1 ORDER BY total_row DESC
```

I want ot know how to embed the like statment since the field5 has one or more data separated by commas as string

ex. field5 has "cat,dog,mouse"

so field2 is looking for total row of like "dog"

Hope you can help me with it.

Comment: Keep in mind that wildcard LIKE searches are very slow on large tables (since they must search the entire contents of the table). At some point, you will need to break this "tag" field out into a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like this, assuming there are no spaces after the commas:

```
select field1, field2, (
        select count(*)
        from table2 as t2
        where t2.field5 = t1.field2
            or t2.field5 like t1.field2 + ',%'
            or t2.field5 like '%,' + t1.field2 + ',%'
            or t2.field5 like '%,' + t1.field2
        ) as total_row
from table1 as t1
order by total_row desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate comma's on the front and back of each field:

```
SELECT field1
      ,field2
      ,( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM table2 as t2 
         WHERE ','+t2.field5+',' LIKE '%,' + t1.field2 + ',%') as total_row 
FROM table1 as t1 ORDER BY total_row DESC
```

Not sure if the above works in MySQL, might need `CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT field1
      ,field2
      ,( SELECT COUNT(*) 
         FROM table2 as t2 
         WHERE CONCAT(',',t2.field5,',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',t1.field2,',%') as total_row 
FROM table1 as t1 ORDER BY total_row DESC
```